# Rate Limiting Policy for Azure to limit specific subscriptions not working as intended

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, rate-limiting

I have this in my inbound policy:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Name=="someName")" />
    <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Name=="otherName")" />
    <otherwise>
        <rate-limit calls="50" renewal-period="300" remaining-calls-variable-name="remainingCallsPerSubscription" />
    </otherwise>
</choose>
```

It does not seem to work as intended, throttling also the above named subscriptions, am I missing something?

p.s. I am on the consumption model

Comment: What is your understanding for the rate-limit policy?

Comment: @MoHaidar I understand that it applies the described rate on a per subscription basis (as per documentation). I would just like to exempt two subscriptions from this via policy. I understand this is possible via product scoping but I am currently looking for a different solution.

Comment: @ZirconCode what is the error you are getting by applying this policy?

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce the error, I was expecting a 429 and got a 500. I will close the question if it does not come back. Seems to work as intended now.

Comment: @ZirconCode Yes, even the given policy works for me as expected

Comment: I am receiving BackendConnectionFailure in my APIM, but it is intermittent and unpredictable, but comes from the policy change. Haven't discovered more yet...

Comment: @ZirconCode Have you added any other policy or only using rate-limit? You can know more about the issue in Trace

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin there is no other policy active on any level. The trace tells me this: `BackendConnectionFailure:
   at forward-request` , the client gets a 500 error. This only happens when the above policy is active, and only sporadically. Still trying to nail it down. Thank you for the great answer below. MSFT hints that this is an SSL issue (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshoot-500-backendconnectionfailure-ssl-tls-error/ba-p/3700074) but I can't see how that can be caused by the policy change.

Comment: ` An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

Comment: @ZirconCode I f you are getting BackendConnectionFailure, then your request is failing while trying to connect to the backend url

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same policy to exempt the subscription keys which are being used from `rate-limit` policy.

For testing purpose, I have taken 10 calls.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Name=="test")" />
            <when condition="@(context.Subscription.Name=="demo")" />
            <otherwise>
                <rate-limit calls="10" renewal-period="300" remaining-calls-variable-name="remainingCallsPerSubscription" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

While testing, you need to pass the subscription key name is ***Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key*** and the value will be the value of your subscription key or else it will fetch the value of `context.Subscription.Name`  as `Built-in all-access subscription` by default.

[image]
[image]

When the value of `context.Subscription.Name` is false, I am getting expected response as shown below.

[image]

[image]
[image]

In order to get the expected response, please make sure you don't have any other policy defined at global or API level.